# How to Change and edit Selected Array from textfield select

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of data and i want to display their value using textfield in the form of defaultValue and we can change which array of data is displayed using a select textfield. then we can edit the data and submit using a button

this is the array

```
const [dataPerfo, setDataPerfo] = useState(
    [
      {
        interval_no: 1,
        id: A,
        status_date: 23-06-2010,
      },
      {
        interval_no: 2,
        id: B,
        status_date: 17-08-1945,
      },
      {
        interval_no: 3,
        id: C,
        status_date: 15-07-2015,
      },
    ]
  )

const handleChangePerfo = (prop) => (event) => {
    setDataPerfo({ ...dataPerfo, [prop]: event.target.value });
  };

return (
<div>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Interval No. :
      </td>
      <td>
        <TextField
          select
          value={dataPerfo.no}
          onChange={handleChange('interval_no')}>
          {dataPerfo.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.interval_no} value={option.interval_no}>
              {option.interval_no}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Status Date :
      </td>
      <td>
        <TextField
          value={dataPerfo.status_date}
          onChange={handleChange('status_date')}
        >
          {dataPerfo.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.status_date} value={option.status_date}>
              {option.status_date}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ID :
      </td>
      <td>
        <TextField
          value={dataPerfo.id}
          onChange={handleChange('id')}
        >
          {dataPerfo.map((option) => (
            <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
              {option.id}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </TextField>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
)
```

i dont know how to display the value of id and status_date based on the value we select on Interval No. so when we select interval no 1, the ID textfield will have the defaultValue of A and status date the value of 23-06-2010. Then we can edit it and later submit it with a button. i'm also wondering is it easier to change the array format?